# How can get value difference between columns in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a simple column charts in this example.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvT85/105/)
I tried this code.

```
 $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
            },

            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of fruits'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat : '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>', shared : true

            },

            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
            },
            {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 1, 4, 4, 3]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

I wonder how to get a difference instead of total in the tooltip actions. 
I want to display on column like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WstyG.png)

Comment: You can use formatter for making your chart. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/wvT85/107/

Comment: Thanks so much! This was what i needed